# What is the difference between "el examen fue largo" and "el examen estuvo largo"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, cópulas

What is the difference between el "examen fue largo" and "el examen estuvo largo"?

Comment: What did you investigate so far? Note there are quite a lot of questions/answers on this topic, so doing some research can satisfy your needs. For avid users: [Necesitamos una pregunta canónica sobre ser/estar](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2498/1674)

Comment: The question is somewhat incomplete. It lacks a context, and it does not show a previous effort. The more information you provide, the more we will be able to help you. Welcome to [spanish.se]!

Comment: Spanish people never say "El examen estuvo largo..." that's a incorrect expression

Answer (score 3):

In the Spanish from Spain the former one is used, while the American Spanish uses the second one. There is no difference but the localization, but *el examen estuvo largo* sounds weird in Spain, as here *largo* is a quality, not a state.

Answer (score 1):

"El examen **estuvo** largo" is a colloquial way of saying "el examen fue largo" in some Latin American regions.

The correct way is "el examen **fue** largo", but both are accepted.
In those regions, "estuvo" is used just like "it was".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you complete it with some sources for your statement? I wasn't aware that this was just a colloquial form.

Comment: @fedorqui The "estuvo largo" is more likely to be said in México

Comment: In Chile both sentences are identical. "_Estuvo largo_" is not colloquial, is not wrong, is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

This really boils down to the difference in

### Ser vs Estar

> **Fue largo** el examen

just means... *it was a long test*

> **Estuvo largo** el examen

means you're telling a story involving this long test. Consider these English differences.

#### Ser

> How was the test? It was a long test.

#### Estar

> Yesterday, I had to pick up my little sister after taking a test.  It was a long test, and I was constantly distracted by the pretty teacher.

The first example is very passive, while the second example really emphasizes the length of the test.

> Ayer assistía a mi clase y me sorprendió que hubo un examen.  Estuvo un examen largo.

*It can also mean that the test was unusually long*

Comment: While this could be a case, in Latin America they use _Estuvo largo_ with the exact same meaning of _it was a long test_.